# BIRT: Gradient Across Chart instead of Bars

Tags: gradient, bar-chart, birt, styling

I want to style my chart in BIRT Designer Pro such that I have a color gradient moving across the bars. I know this can be accomplished using the format chart editor and adjusting the series palette to have a color gradient, but this doesn't achieve quite what I want to accomplish. My chart looks like this currently:[image] You can see that the gradient moves across all the bars from start to finish no matter how long the bars are. In reality, what I want to accomplish can be seen in this Photoshop render: [image]

In this image you can see how the gradient depends on how long the bar is and does not extend all the way between both colors of the gradient. Is it possible to do something like this in BIRT via scripting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be very simple to fix in the BIRT Designer. All that was needed was a custom theme with the following Highcharts.js needed to style it:

`color: {
     linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, '100%'],
         stops: [
             [0, '#FCB314'],
             [1, '#EF6F00']
         ]
 }`

The crucial piece of this was the addition of the 100% when specifying the gradient in the first place.